# CUDA Unified Memory Programming - Can I pass a pointer to modules which are not aware of CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I will allocate some memory with `cudaMallocManaged`. Can I safely pass this pointer to another program module (Which is compiled into another .o file) that is not aware of CUDA and will just juse plain memcpy or something to manipulate the data behind the pointer?

Something like that

```
// compiled into A.o
class A{
  void* getMem(int size){
    void* ptr;
    cudaMallocManaged(*ptr, size);
    return ptr;
  }

  // some kernels here

}


// compiled into B.o
class B{
  void manipulateMem(void* ptr, void* source, int size){
    memcpy(ptr, source, size);
  }

}
```

And then a code like that, maybe compiled into main.o:

```
A a;
B b;
void* mem = a.getMem(100);
b.manipulateMem(mem, source, 100);
```

I did not find any notices that automatic copying/synchronizing should not work in that case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can I safely pass this pointer to another program module (Which is compiled into another .o file) that is not aware of CUDA and will just juse plain memcpy or something to manipulate the data behind the pointer?

Yes, you can, but the [Unified Memory access rules](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-coherency-hd) (<- hint: click on this and read this) must still be adhered to. For GPUs with compute capability 3.0 or higher but less than 6.0,  these rules *currently* are:

1. Initially, upon allocation (using a managed allocator such as `cudaMallocManaged`), and before any kernels have been called, a managed pointer is accessible from (code running on) the host CPU.
2. Once any kernel has been called, and until a subsequent `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` has been called, the data is *inaccessible* from host code, and any attempts to use it in host code will result in UB, which may include seg faults.
3. After a synchronization event (e.g. `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`), host access to the data referenced by the managed pointer is restored. (Technically, in the current implementation, host access to data at this point will normally result in page-faults, an OS-visible event.  These page faults basically call into the CUDA runtime, which then does the necessary `cudaMemcpy` operations under the hood, to return the data to the host, to service the page fault.  But these comments in parenthesis are not necessary for understanding the general rules of behavior.)

So, the CUDA runtime has basically explicit markers (kernel launch -> synchronize) that explicitly identify to it how to manage the data (when to migrate and in which direction).  So even though you have code running in some "module ... that is not aware of CUDA", if the above rules are adhered to, the code in that module will have access to the data, because the CUDA runtime has adequate, explicit markers that identify to it how to manage the data.

For GPUs of compute capability 6.0 or higher, the above rules essentially do not apply. For these GPUs, concurrent access by the host and device *is* possible, but multiple access to a common resource still presents the possibility for race conditions as in any multi-processor/multi-threaded environment.  *Currently*, the CUDA runtime does not enforce any specific access ordering rules between host and device access to the same *page* of memory.

Comment: Note that this answer needs to be updated for Pascal and later GPUs, which changes 1-3. Pascal GPUs and CPUs can access managed memory at the same time, with the caveat that race conditions must be correctly handled as in any multiprocessor shared memory code. 1-3 still apply to earlier GPUs.

Comment: Can c++ host atomics go well with cuda device atomics for a volta using unified mem? Fine grained job offload for example? Using gpu side atomic spinwait and cpu side atomic increment to signal things to gpu? Quicker than kernel launch overhead?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the CUDA unified memory model is there explicitly to allow this kind of access: Not only can the GPU access unified memory pointers directly. In the same way a part of the program running on the host CPU will have unified access including GPU memory. Be aware of bus bandwidth bottlenecks though.

Comment: Thanks! But this still sounds magic to me. Could you maybe add a few words how this actually works? How does a program module know that it has to synchronize the memory when it is completely unaware of CUDA?

Comment: @Michael: I don't believe it does. GPU actions cause page level synchronisation, host actions do not.

Comment: @Michael: In the same way a program "knows" that some part of its address space is in fact not in RAM but on a hard disk, or some control registers of a piece or hardware: Virtual memory. The address space your program sees is, well, virtual. Whenever an access is made a piece of the CPU is using data in address translation tables to decide where the accesses address is actually residing. If its on the GPU, then it jumps to the driver which translates it into the physical PCI space address that maps to the memory on the GPU.

Comment: @datenwolf: Thanks for that explanation! But now I'm concerned about talonmies statement... What is true?

Comment: @Michael: "Pages" are an inherent concept of virtual memory. And depending on how a driver implements it, things may happen on a page level. However in the case of CUDA, no, there's no page level synchronization. The relevant parts of the GPU memory (which looks to the naked CPU just as another part of the physical address space, just at another location) is mapped into the process. Virtual memory takes care of the rest.

Comment: @datenwolf: Are you sure that is correct? From my understanding Managed memory (not talking about UVA or mapped memory here) *does* involved GPU driver initiated page level migration and synchronisation between the GPU and host when the GPU reads and writes from managed allocations.

Comment: @talonmies: In case of managed memory you're right of course.

Comment: So the answer still holds or do I have to pay special attention to something?

Comment: @Michael: From your point of view the answer still holds. The process is completely transparent to the process. The difference is in the details, how the data is transferred between GPU and CPU. In a UVA/mapped memory situation when the host processor accesses some address range that's associated with GPU memory the access goes directly to the GPU. In case of a managed memory situation, when accessing the address space associated with the memory, the CUDA driver will perform the synchronizing copy operations in the background. However for the process this is just as transparent as swap space.